# comparing fields in 2 different tables using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to compare if the address fields in contact table are different to that of the delivery table.

```
SELECT contactID, addressline1
FROM contact
where contactID = '0018319'
```

Below is the delivery table which contains the old details.

```
SELECT contactID, addressline1
FROM delivery
where contactID = '0018319'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT contactID, d.addressline1, c.addressline1
FROM delivery d
INNER JOIN contact c on d.contactID = c.contactID
where d.addressline1 != c.addressline1
```

Comment: @Mark yes, if its only that row that needs to be compared and not the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a flag, then you would use `case` in the `select` statement:

```
select contactId,
       (case when d.addressline1 = c.addressline1 or d.addressline1 is null and c.addressline1 is null
             then 'SAME'
             else 'DIFFERENT'
        end) as SameOrDifferent
from contact c join
     delivery d
     on c.contactId = d.contactId
where contactId = '0018319';
```

This is going to compare each address in the two tables.

If you want to know if *all* are the same, then the query is more complicated.  The idea is to do a `full outer join` between the two table (for the given `contractid`) on `addressline1`.  If all the addresslines match, then the `full outer join` will never produce `NULL` values.  If any are missing (on either side), then there will be NULL values.

```
select coalesce(c.contactId, d.contactId) as contactId,
       (case when sum(case when c.addressline1 is null or d.addressline1 is null
                           then 1
                           else 0
                       end) = 0
             then 'SAME'
             else 'DIFFERENT'
        end) as SameOrDifferent
from (select c.* from contact c where c.contactId = '0018319') c full outer join
     (select d.* from delivery d where d.contactId = '0018319') d
     on c.addressline1 = d.addressline1 and
        c.contactId = d.contactId  -- not actually necessary but useful for multiple contacts
group by coalesce(c.contactId, d.contactId)
```

Comment: @bluefeet . . . If you are interested it is fixed.  It also reminds me of why I don't like standard SQL for solving this sort of question.